# Spark orc partitioning strategy for multiple keys

Tags: apache-spark, orc

When storing transactions there are often a few different keys on which to filter the query for different use cases. E.g. card ID, account No, customer No, date

The transactions could be partioned by date as:

```
jdbcDF.write.format("orc").partitionBy("TX_Date").save("transactions")
```

Now I could quickly aggregate transactions for specific months, but what if I want to aggregate the transactions based on e.g. customer No?

Would it be better to store a transaction id with every transaction row, and keep separate lookup tables (link tables) that are partioned by the most common keys?
E.g. the following lookup tables:

Card ID | TransID

Customer No | TransID

Account No | TransID

TX_Date | TransID

Is this an anti-pattern for spark & orc development or are there better ways to "index" on different keys? (In the orc-files I already use row indexes)

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://streever.atlassian.net/wiki/display/HADOOP/Optimizing+ORC+Files+for+Query+Performance):

> The index is a data structure that includes min and max values for each column and the row positions within each column

ORC is a columnar file format and it's not indexed in the way SQL is.
the `partitionBy` controls data locality or how files are split.

Make sure rows are evenly distributed in the file by choosing a diverse partitionBy key and run tests to confirm you did the correct choice.

Comment: partitionBy splits the data into folders by that key. That means, that if I search for a specific range or a specific key, spark could skip all the others without even reading the orc-files in the folders.
The question is, can I achieve having the data partitioned by multiple keys, by creating the lookup tables as suggested. Or more specifically will it increase the performance.

Comment: You will probably not get a speed increase due to what I wrote in the answer